# Story ID: Sci-Fi Future with Giant Women and Cloned men

Tags: story-identification

Cant Remember the author or the name of this novel/short story.
A man wakes up in the future that has giant 8 foot tall women who clone men and use them as slaves. He manages to have sex with one of them.
I remember that they find out and he has to run.
Sorry for being so short on the info. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't remember space being involved. It was a short book, maybe 200 pages or shorter. I remember the main character hiding below a couple of industrial pipelines on the cover art. It was a "man on the run" kinda story. I should also add that the society had a modified reproduction system where they either messed around with the men or there was a mono-gender system.

Great job with the book you suggested. My girlfriend is a fanatic feminist, I brought up the content of this book and she was really excited to read it. Ill forward your suggestion to her.

Answer (score 3):

There's a short story by by James Tiptree, Jr., [*Mama Come Home,*](https://outofeverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/mamma-come-home-review/) that has giant women:

> There they stood on their ramp, three
>   magnificent earth-type young females in space-opera uniforms.
>       Helmets on the backs of their heads and
>   double-curve grins on their long mouths. The leader was older and had
>   more glitter on her crest. She swung back her droopy wing of hair,
>   breathed twice, wrinkled her nose and paced down the ramp to meet the
>   U.N. President.
>      Then we got it. The U.N.
>   President that year was an Ethiopian about six feet five. The top of
>   his head came just to the buckle on her crossbelt.
>       I guess the world wide hush quivered—it
>   certainly did in George’s projection room.
>       “About eight-foot-three for the captain,” I
>   said.

The alien women's men are very much second-class citizens, though not clones. One of the Human (male) main characters is raped by some of the women and escapes alive, just barely.

Comment: I can't say that it looks like the right match to me, other than involving giant women, sex, and slaves, but that's up to the original querent. It's certainly close enough to get an upvote for the effort.

Comment: @Sean Duggan: I know it's a long shot, but I've had longer ones come through.